# Compositing doesn't work, I have chosen Use Node. - Blender 3.0

Tags: rendering

I want to add a background, there is no problem with the Viewer display, but the background is really transparent after rendering, please help me.
[image]

Comment: You can try saving the image from the viewer node, in the rendering tab switch the image to "Viewer Node" and you should be able to save it

Comment: you did not connect it to the compositor node

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: deleted my answer...you were right

Comment: Still it can be a different issue, though. For example, old render cache needs to be re-rendered.